# Power BI dataframe table visualization

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, powerbi

Power BI has a Python visualization element. It creates dataframe from fields of Power BI data source, and then visualize it with `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` method.

I need to visualize dataframe in table form (with ability to color cells depending on different data conditions)

Problem is that any example of table visualizaions of dataframes doesn't work inside Power BI Py element (and doesn't says what the problem is) even when it works in Anaconda.

Can somebody show a working example of dataframe table visualisation for Power BI?

Answer (score 5):

I created data in a dataframe to keep the example simple. This could also be the output of manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,20,2), 'b': range(10,30,2)})
print(dataset)

    a   b
0   0  10
1   2  12
2   4  14
3   6  16
4   8  18
5  10  20
6  12  22
7  14  24
8  16  26
9  18  28
```

In a new Power BI file,

```
1. Get Data/More/Other/Python Script
```

Paste in:

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame({'a': range(0,20,2), 'b': range(10,30,2)})
# Note the use of pandas, not pd
```

In the Navigator window, select 'dataset' under Python

Select Load or Transform Data if you wish to manipulate the data.

Once loaded you can to visualization and use the data just like any other table.

[image: Python Data with color for values]

#### EDIT

While the question is closed because it was not focussed. I think this is what the op was looking for.

In Power BI, create a dataset as follows from python script:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 8), columns=list('abcdefgh'))
```

Use matplotlib.pyplot to create a heatmap from the table. You can control the heatmap more extensively than in this example.

So in visualization in Power BI, add the following python script (taken from [Conditional formatting for 2- or 3-scale coloring of cells of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748570/conditional-formatting-for-2-or-3-scale-coloring-of-cells-of-a-table)):

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:

import pandas as pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Round to two digits to print nicely
vals = np.around(dataset.values, 2)
#Normalize data to [0, 1] range for color mapping below
normal = (dataset - dataset.min()) / (dataset.max() - dataset.min())

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
the_table=ax.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=dataset.index, colLabels=dataset.columns, 
                   loc='center', cellColours=plt.cm.RdYlGn(normal),animated=True)

plt.show()
```

From this you get:

[image: Matplotlib heatmap]

If you refresh your data, the script will yeild a new heatmap, which is what should happen in your power bi if you update whatever data you are using. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough: I don't need to load data with python, I already have preloaded data. I need to set some complex visualisation rules into Py vusualizations, because Power BI format tools are not eve close enough

Comment: OIC, I did misunderstand you. Your question is closed as it is not focussed/clear enough. Help me understand exactly what you are looking for. We'll updaate the question and hopefully get help. You have a python dataframe, and you want to create a table in python that has colors for conditions. Is that what I'm understanding? If you look at my dataframe, can you take that, put it into your questions, and then give an example of output that would be what you are looking for?

Comment: On Visualization panel there a lot of pictagrams of possible diagrams . One of them is [Py] - "Python visuals". It can implement python code to show visualization of different python libraries like matplotlib, seaborn, etc. It can take in any data loaded in Power Bi and makes dataframe of it.

The problem is that the only way this element works is when python code is like this

#autogenerated code:
#import pandas
#import matplolib.pyplot
#dataset = df.read_csv(fields that you add to [Py])

matplotlib.pyplot.show()

I can't find code examples that wil visualize 'dataset' as a table